# Tdd workflow when you find Single Responsibility Principle violation

Tags: tdd, single-responsibility-principle

I trying to follow TDD. So here is my problem

I have interface *Risk* with method

```
boolean check(...)
```

Risk1, and Risk2 are implentations deveped test first, so now they are fully covered.
I decided that unit that check all risks (*CompositeRisk*) also could implement *Risk*. 
CompositeRisk applies OR on each Risk1 and Risk2 rezult (If one risk is true then whole this is risky). Still everything is test first.

Now I am looking to one of the risk and thinking - this one has word "AND" and checks different fields. It seems that I can split it to two object and create one more *CompositeAndRisk* which would apply And on both splitted risks. This way I could construct DSL for risks decision tree (seems nice because risks rules could changes a lot).

So what I should do with risk's I split tests? Should I rename i to CompositeAndRiskTest? should I delete it?, should I write test for splitClasses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest that you turn the `CompositeRisk` class into an interface, and have two separate subclasses of it: `CompositeOrRisk` and `CompositeAndRisk`. This is just about the design though.

Regarding your question, I believe there's no single right answer, so let me share how I see it.
As you know, in TDD there are concrete steps you follow (that comprise the TDD cycle), and there's a specific state the tests should be at in between each of them. Here's what I mean:

```
[State = No tests]  
1. Write a test that fails  
[State = Test fails]
2. Write as little code as possible in order for the test to pass  
[State = Test passes]  
3. Refactor  
[State = Test still passes]
```

Given that this is what we aim for in TDD, I would do the changes you're talking about in the refactoring phase, including refactoring the tests accordingly.
This means that if I'm splitting a class, I'll be splitting the relevant test as well. At no point should the tests fail, as I'm only changing the structure of the code, not what it does (this is the meaning of refactoring after all).

If you have a larger change to do though, I would go about creating a new class from scratch (TDD of course), and later on, remove the no longer needed functionality from the old class, as well as the now redundant test cases.

Comment: Well my idea was to rename CompositeRisk to CompositeOrRisk. Create CompositeAndRisk. Both implementing Risk (same interface that Component implemnts). I could probably rename the clas I want so split  to CompositeAndRisk and exctract functionality to new classes. But it seems that my test now would test unnecessary details.  It seems your sugestion to split tests is optimal

Comment: That's pretty much what I'm talking about. The only thing I would consider other than that, is to have a common interface `CompositeRisk` to the `CompositeOrRisk` and `CompositeAndRisk`, since you might want to add some more composites later on, and maybe add functionality to it (make it extend `Iterable<Risk>` or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

The approach I'd take in this case is "*play it innocent*" -- when you discover a new requirement, just write a test and the implementation for it, pretending to ignore the relationship with previous requirements at first.

The "And" case here is clearly new functionality. No need to modify the contents of the existing test at that point, just create another test with a name that reflects the new requirement, such as `CompositeAndRiskTest` and create the corresponding implementation.

Then, during the Refactor step, "realize" that the two previous objects are 2 sides of the same coin and refactor them accordingly. That could just mean renaming `CompositeRisk` to `CompositeOrRisk`, or more complex things.

Once the 2 sorts of Risks are identified, tested and implemented, you could go on and create new tests for combinations of them.